# Failed conversion of varchar to datetime. Two similarly structured date, but only one passes

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I am inserting two datetime values as varchars. The data type of the relevant columns is `DATETIME` for both (unlike the column name suggests, `PERFORMANCEDATE` is `DATETIME`, and so is `PERFORMANCETIME`). The test data is generated using tools, so I can't change them as they are thousands of lines.

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
GO

INSERT INTO CONCERT (PERFORMANCEDATE, TOWNNAME, PERFORMANCETIME, LOCATION, TITLE) 
VALUES ('1993-5-2 13:26:22', 'X', '1604-9-13 12:0:48', 'X', 'X')

INSERT INTO CONCERT (PERFORMANCEDATE, TOWNNAME, PERFORMANCETIME, LOCATION, TITLE) 
VALUES ('1102-11-26 9:4:56', 'X', '1534-2-10 11:34:36', 'X', 'X')
```

The first insert works fine, but the second insert throws this error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Why does the second one fail? In fact, every single insert aside from the first one fails.

Comment: I'm surprised the first one doesn't fail as well. Sql Server's datetime has a range of January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql

Comment: The start year might actually be the issue, I'll look into it.

Comment: Another problem can be the format of your time: Minutes only 1 digit.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: Yes I did. The issue was the date being before the minimum. I can't mark the question as solved though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server datetime has a minimum date of January 1, 1753. If you can change the column you are inserting into to be a datetime2, that will solve your problem as it has a minimum date of ‘0001-01-01’ with a max of ‘9999-12-31’

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql

Also note that in the reference to datetime, Microsoft even suggests that you SHOULD use datetime2:

*Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. time, datetime2 and datetimeoffset provide more seconds precision. datetimeoffset provides time zone support for globally deployed applications.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql